# Django compatibility issues with Python 3.2

Tags: django, compatibility, python-3.2

```
OS: windows 7 (x64)
Python: 3.2
Django: 1.3.1
```

So I am trying to install Django and am getting the following error:

```
file "setup.py", line 70 
if u'SVN' in version:  
syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I know this is a compatibility issue with python3.2 and would not be a problem if I re-install python 2.6 instead. My question is there a way around this now? Or is Django still only compatible with python2.6 only?

Comment: Unfortunately, django 1.3.x isn't python 3 compatible, so even if you get past the installation error, you'll likely run into other issues. A further update is that django 1.4 and SVN trunk might have better 3.x compatibility, but I have not kept up to date.

Comment: definitely look at using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) if you plan on keeping 3.2 as your global python version and want to just use 2.X for Django. Actually, if you don't use virtualenv already, consider using it for every django project anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django 1.3.1 is compatible with Python versions from 2.4 to 2.7.

There are people working on an [experimental port to Python 3 now](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/django/). But for the time being your best bet is to install Python 2.7.

Update: There is official work being done to port Django to Python 3. See [this blog post](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/aug/19/experimental-python-3-support/) for more information.